# Как сделать чтобы это значение присваивалось только к <ul> который находится в header?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

```css
ul {
  /*убираем маркеры списка*/
  list-style: none;
  /*убираем отступы*/
  margin: 0;
  /*убираем отступы*/
  padding-left: 0;
  /*делаем отступ сверху*/
  margin-top: 25px;
  /*добавляем фон всему меню*/
  background: #170931;
  /*задаем высоту*/
  height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: header ul { ... } или добавьте класс какой-то списку

Comment: @humster_spb Спасибо!